# Mock all instances of a component with Vitest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, vitest

I have a couple components that really only provide aesthetic flourishes on a few projects. In tests they cause problems due to timing, use of things like Canvas...

In most instances I just want to mock them out. Is there a shortcut to doing this aside form using `vi.mock('../my/component/Here', ...)` in every test file?